# What subtitle formats are supported by Chromecast?

Tags: chromecast, subtitle, closed-captions

What subtitle formats are supported by Chromecast (when streaming HLS and) when using the Default Receiver?

/BE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- TTML - Timed Text Markup Language
- WebVTT - Web Video Text Tracks
- CEA-608